# enable Forecasts and other settings via CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, automation, setup, cli

In order to prepare new scratch org I need to enable a few settings. Those settings are: enable Forecsts, enable Scheduling, enable Field Service, and few more... This is doable by clicking in appropriate Setup section (see example on attached picture). [image: enable Forecasts]

What I need is to do the same from CLI to make it automatic. Is there any way to do it via sfdx CLI or any other command line tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/49) to figure out the JSON you need to enable specific features. You use this JSON file *while* creating the Scratch Org:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/my-scratch-org-config.json
```

For example:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "productSettings": {
       "enableRevenueSchedule": true
     }
  }
}
```

You can also deploy most of these settings with force:source:deploy or force:mdapi:deploy, but then you need a separate deploy step.